# Write to/Create text file in C# on initialization of a window

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am creating a .net GUI that will change color based on what is written in a text file. I am having trouble figuring out how to use StreamWriter to create the text file, more specifically where the code should go. This is my first attempt using VS and C# so I am a bit lost.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.IO;


namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox2_Copy14_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Copy5_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void CC_Futs_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

    {

    }

    private void FCOJ_Futs_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    }

}
```

Where in this code would I use StreamWriter to create the text file and could you provide an example of code you might use? You can ignore the click events for the button at this time, just trying to understand the overall structure here.

Comment: Why do you want to write to the file? What would you write? From the description it sounds like you want to read the file.

Comment: On startup I want to dump the file and write a new one if it is a new date. I am just trying to get the structure right, I think if I can understand where you would just write a standard text file on startup, I can handle the rest.

Comment: "So I want to dump the file and write a new one" tells us --- you need to read in the old file, unless dump means delete then....ahh you see its a bit confusing what you want as you haven't tried anything for us to help you with.  We don't know what dump means to you, is it checking the contents of the file, checking creation date...ect.... in short the answer is (with what you gave us): anywhere in the code you have is fine, or create a new method specifically for writing to a new file.

Answer (score 0):

To read or write a text file when the Windows form application starts you need to use the Form load event. The load event happens before the form is shown. This example should be enough to get you going.

```
     private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
                //Write to a file
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath + @"\file.txt");
                sw.WriteLine("some text here");
                sw.Close();
                sw.Dispose();

                //read from a file
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Application.StartupPath + @"\file.txt");
                String line = null;

                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(line);
                }

               sr.Close();
               sr.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Why not using *using* instead of *close/dispose*? Much better way would be using *File.ReadAllText* or *File.WriteAllText*

Comment: @Eser What exactly is the difference using using instead of what I did? If you wish do to something for each line of text my loop works, and provides the same as File.ReadAllText if you just add them up in a string variable. It provides more flexibility.

Comment: I don't say it's wrong.  **1)** Suppose an exception occurs in your while-loop. your code exits without closing the file. so **using{.....}** is much better. **2)** Why would you write all these codes when you can do it in one line? Do you think  "suggesting shorter and better alternatives" is a bad thing?

Comment: @Eser I would definitely have a try / catch / finally around this code in my program and clean up, but I am trying to answer the question, not teaching how to program. And of course if you can use one line of code to accomplish what you need instead of what I wrote that's great, but I use this while loop in a lot of places, and I need the ability many times to work on every line of a file I read in. Not just read in an entire file. Your suggestions are completely valid.